# Does std::string::resize(smaller_than_capacity) guarantee existing iterators are still valid?

Tags: c++, string, vector, standards, c++20

According to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize), `std::vector::resize` explicitly guarantees:

> Vector capacity is never reduced when resizing to smaller size because
> that would invalidate all iterators, rather than only the ones that
> would be invalidated by the equivalent sequence of `pop_back()` calls.

However, I cannot find any similar guarantee from the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) of `std::string::resize`.

**Does** `std::string::resize(smaller_than_capacity)` **guarantee existing iterators are still valid?**

Comment: Resizing to less than the current `capacity` never reallocates memory, that is what `shrink_to_fit()` was introduced for. But if the new `size` is less than the current `size`, then any existing iterators `>=` the old `size` should be invalidated since they would now be past the new `end`.

Comment: Is there any citation?

Comment: I don't know, but such an invalidation is just logical thinking, since no iterator can be valid past the current `end`, so if `end` is moved, old iterators should become invalid if they are past the new `end`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it is not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: A string when resizing smaller might be (could be) moved into the SSO area which would cause invalidation.

Comment: @RichardCritten unless the string's `iterator` class were implemented in such a way to take that into account, where deferencing an iterator would access either the SSO area or dynamic memory, whichever is currently in use. I don't think changing the backing memory would require an iterator to be invalidated if it is still logically pointing at the same character.  But, this is an implementation detail, so who knows what would happen...

Comment: fwiw, also the complexity is another hint that `std::string::resize` behaves differently than `std::vector::resize`. For string it is linear in the size of the string, while for vector it is only linear in difference between difference in current and requested size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such requirement does not exist in Standard. See 21.3.3.2:

> References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a
> basic_­string sequence may be invalidated by the following uses of
> that basic_­string object:

> (4.1) Passing as an argument to any
> standard library function taking a reference to non-const
> basic_­string as an argument.

> (4.2) Calling non-const member
> functions, except operator[], at, data, front, back, begin, rbegin,
> end, and rend.